# Which role does the order of object spread and other properties play?

Tags: javascript, spread-syntax

Consider an object `data`.

```
data = {
  draggingTaskId: '',
  entities: {},
  selectedTaskIds: [],
}
```

I am using destructuring assignment in two different orders, but the behaviour is different both the times. Does order matter in Object destructuring assignment?

```
console.log('----------------------------------');

console.log({
  ...data,
  draggingTaskId: "task-0",
});

console.log({
  draggingTaskId: "task-0",
  ...data,
});

console.log('----------------------------------');
```

Output:

```
--------------------------------

draggingTaskId: "task-0"
entities: {}
selectedTaskIds: []

draggingTaskId: ""
entities: {}
selectedTaskIds: []

-----------------------------------
```

In the second instance, the `draggingTaskId` is coming out as an empty string.

Comment: _"Does order matter in Object destruction assignment?"_  from your testing, you should be able to answer this yourself

Comment: It's is as simple as the order in which you have written it, as first in object you assigned a value but then when you are spreading another object into it which has same key but different value, it is over ridden...

Comment: your mistaken with the second result https://playcode.io/646080/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The order is indeed relevant - items that appear later override items that appear earlier, if they have the same keys.

```js
console.log({
  ...data,
  draggingTaskId: 'task-0', // this overrides the value of data.draggingTaskId = '', resulting in 'task-0'
})
console.log({
  draggingTaskId: 'task-0', // In this case this key is overridden by the value of data.draggingTaskId = '', resulting in ''
  ...data,
})
```

You may find this helpful - https://dmitripavlutin.com/object-rest-spread-properties-javascript/#21-object-spread-rule-latter-property-wins

Comment: My understanding initially was that spreading order doesn't matter and it just spreads the remaining keys.